# membership and inclusion doubt with power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working on these questions and I'm very confused about the difference between membership and inclusion.

If $a\in P(A∩B)\setminus C $ then:

1. $(a\in D\setminus C)$ where $D = P(A \cap B)$;
2. $a\subset (A \cap B)$ AND $(a \not\subset C)$;
3. $a\subset(A \cap B)$ AND $(a \notin C)$;
4. $a\subset A$ AND $a\subset B$.

Is the membership valid only between an element and a set or no?
And in the inclusion valid only between sets? 
I searched a lot to do this exercise but i don't understand

Comment: Every element is a set itself, so you can talk about membership and inclusion between any element and/or set

Comment: @Exodd can you give me an example of answers 2 and 3 please?

Comment: But you have to prove every of them, or it's a true/false?

Comment: sorry it's true/false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In elemental set theory, every element is a set itself. The expression 
$$a\in P(A\cap B)$$
is the proof of it, since $a$ is a subset of $A$ and $B$. In simbols,
$$a\subset (A\cap B)$$
For example, set 
$$A=\{ 0 , 1 , \{ 0, 1 \}   \}$$
$$B=\{ 0 , 1 ,  \{ 0 \} \}$$
in this case
$$A\cap B =  \{ 0, 1 \}$$
$$P(A\cap B)= \{  \{ \},  \{ 0 \}, \{  1 \} , \{ 0, 1 \}\}$$
If 
$$a= \{ 0, 1 \}$$
then the following statements are both true 
$$a\in A\qquad a\subset A$$

Comment: Ok now it is better:) Last question: a ⊆ A ∩ B e a ̸⊆ C is true? And a ⊆ A ∩ B e a ̸∈ C is true? Because now for me both are true..am i right?

Comment: Try with $C=B$ and answer by yourself